# Error: data and salt arguments required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save a user to mongodb database using post request as follow, but I got the error bcrypt Error: data and hash arguments required .It's a pretty simple set up of the code but i can't figure out anything wrong with it.
models/users.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const confic = require('../models/users');

// User schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
 },
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 username:{
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 password: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id,callback){
 User.findById(id,callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username,callback){
 const query = {username:username}
 User.findOne(query,callback);
}

module.exports.addUser= function (newUser, callback) {
   bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt , (err, hash) =>{
        if(err) throw (err);

        newUser.password=hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
    });
   });
}
```

routes/users.js

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
User = require('../models/users')

// // Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  var newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  User.addUser(newUser, (err, User) => {
    if(err){
      // res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
    } else {
      // res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    }

  });

});

// Authenticate
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('AUTHENTICATE');
});

// Profile
router.get('/profile', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('PROFILE');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Server was running but after using postman chrome post request error are shown and server stop working as errors shown in image.[image]

Comment: Have you verified the contents of the request body at the time of the request?

Comment: ( "name":"abc",
 "email":"abc@gmail.com",
"username":"abcd",
"password":"12345"
)

Comment: this what have sent in body

Comment: Can you confirm that the User record being generated has the password field set at the time that the addUser function is invoked? You might log the contents of the password field either in or before the addUser function.

Comment: Can you log `newUser` before calling `bcrypt.genSalt` in your `User` module please ?

Comment: i dont understand how to do that ** boehm_s**

Comment: Use `await` with `bcrypt.genSalt();` method. work like a charm.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The error comes from the `bcrypt.hash` method.
In your case, you have the following piece of code :

```
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt , (err, hash) => { ... }
```

I think that your problem comes from the `newUser.password` that must be empty (`null` or `undefined`). The error says `data and salt arguments required`. It looks like your salt is correctly generated and you didn't check if `newUser.password === undefined`, so here's my bet: somehow `newUser.password` is undefined.

Also, you can check if the `genSalt` method works fine by adding `if(err) throw (err);` after calling it as you did for the `bcrypt.hash` method.

Comment: And what about logging `newUser` before generating the salt ?

Comment: actually i am not getting how to do that i am just confused abour logging newUsers before generating salt please explain?

Comment: Doing so, you'll be able to check if at this stage of the process, `newUser.password` has a value or if it is `undefined`. Then, if it's `undefined`, the error comes from the data course before getting here

Comment: yes you were right newUsers.password is undefined now what i do to solve this ???

Comment: You can log `newUser` just after it's creation to see if `newUser.password` is undefined at this moment

Comment: newUser.password is defined  every where i am sorry i was confussed but after  if(err) throw (err); program is   stopped errer is thrown  before that newUser.password is defined  everywhere before that

Comment: The program doesn't stops because of the `if(err) throw (err) `, it stops because of the `bcrypt.hash` function. Can you log `newUser` before this line :   `User.addUser(newUser, (err, User) => { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the arrow `=>` in bcrypt.hash() . Use old fashioned method definition `function() {}`

Comment: Actually, lambda expressions work fine. e.g.  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => { console.log(err, hash) })

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the properties are as they are being supplied, in my case, I was sending a `Password` property with a capital `P` and then passing the `password` with a small `p` letter to the `hash` function.

Answer (score 1):

Per mongoose docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html

Q. I'm using an arrow function for a virtual, middleware, getter/setter, or method and the value of this is wrong.

A. Arrow functions handle the this keyword much differently than conventional functions. Mongoose getters/setters depend on this to give you access to the document that you're writing to, but this functionality does not work with arrow functions. Do not use arrow functions for mongoose getters/setters unless do not intend to access the document in the getter/setter.

Answer (score 1):

When I was testing with plain text mode, I got this error (data and salt argument required), once I did change to json, it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing body parser middleware. Should solve the issue.

Here's how to use it in your code.

Install
npm i body-parser

Use as middleware in app.js/server.js,

```
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the password argument you passed isn't defined. I know the req.body.password is supposed to generate the user password, but for some reasons it doesn't work that way. Instead try this

```
 bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(`${password}`, salt , (err, hash) =>{
        if(err) throw (err)
```

What i did was simply use the iterals in passing the password arguments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Error: data and salt arguments required

```
{
    "email": "me4@gmail.com",
    "passsword": "djhsd@92129nnj!"
}
```

It's likely that the password field is not being passed correctly in the request payload. Your code example provides valuable insight into how to properly validate the email and password inputs before attempting to use them.

Sometimes your Postman API checking to go to incorrectly or something this error overcome another wish this error comes from, It looks like your salt is correctly generated and you didn't check `newUser.password === undefined`

Here example code snippet,

```
if (!email || typeof email !== "string") {
    throw Error("Email is required");
}

//valide password
if (!password || typeof password !== "string") {
    throw Error("Password is required");
}

//valide email format
if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
    throw Error("Email is not valid");
}

//valide password length
if (!validator.isLength(password, { min: 6 })) {
    throw Error("Password must be at least 6 characters");
}
```