# for salt and hashing passwords i used Bcrypt method but its showing , error = new Error('data and salt arguments required');

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt, helper

for salt and hashing passwords i used Bcrypt method but its showing ,
error = new Error('data and salt arguments required');
i think my code have the problem please i need help please;
eCommerce website is my project so ,i created signup form in user panel

***user.js**

```
const userHelpers=require('../helpers/user-helpers')
 
router.get('/signup',(req,res)=>{
   res.render('user/signup')
})

router.post('/signup',(req,res)=>{
  userHelpers.doSignup(req.body).then((response)=>{
     console.log(response);
  })
```

***user-helpers.js***

```
var db=require('../config/connection')
 var collection=require('../config/collections')
 const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')

module.exports={
    doSignup:(userData)=>{
        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            // var salt =  await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            userData.Password= await bcrypt.hash(userData.Password ,10)
                db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).insertOne(userData).then((data)=>{

                    resolve(data) 
                });
                     
            });
          
    }
```

***collection.js***

```
module.exports={
    PRODUCT_COLLECTION:'product',
    USER_COLLECTION:'user'
}
```

this is my code but the error shoing

```
error = new Error('data and salt arguments required');
                ^

Error: data and salt arguments required
```

how to fix the problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I got the solution. The problem in the `user-helpers.js`.

`user-helpers.js`

````
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
         
    module.exports={
        doSignup:(userData)=>{
            return new Promise (async(resolve,reject)=>{
          
            userData.password=await bcrypt.hash(userData.password,10)
                   
                      db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).insertOne(userData).then((data)=>{
                        resolve(data) 
                        // console.log(userData.password)
                        // console.log(userData.email)                    
                    });
                    });
                 
         }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you get, it looks like the function `bcrypt.hash` fails because `userData.Password` might not be set.
Make sure that you get the userData.Password correctly with the request.
If you use express you might not have a conversion to JSON so add a middleware to parse the data to JSON, like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
   response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Take a look at these previous questions & answers:

- [Error: data and salt arguments required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015613/error-data-and-salt-arguments-required)
- [How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application)